# Issue with div:hover

Tags: html, css, web, hover

I have this `:hover`:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewhoward_im/hLc42dw3/

```
<a href="#" id="pin1" class="pin"></a>
<span id="pin1-content" class="pin-content">text</span>
```

It's working fine.

However, I've added it to a custom WordPress theme — http://www.letsgobucketlisting.com/ — and I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are CSS rules in your website overriding your custom css rules, try this:

```
.pin-content {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  background-color:#333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#pin1:hover + #pin1-content {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that both the above together worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has added a `<br>` between your anchor and the span...

So your adjacent sibling selector will not work.

```
#pin1:hover + #pin1-content {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Ive added a `<br>` to your fiddle so you can see the result.
http://jsfiddle.net/hLc42dw3/1/

Add your anchor and span on a single line or with a html comment between to prevent the additional line-break tags.

```
<a href="#" id="pin1" class="pin"></a><!--
--><span id="pin1-content" class="pin-content">text</span>
```

Comment: You're welcome, please mark my answer as correct please.

Comment: you wont need to add the `!important` to the style, it will work without it.

Comment: Ive updated your fiddle with the below style and it makes no difference to your problem http://jsfiddle.net/hLc42dw3/2/